Building wheel for griddb_python failed (non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_t')
I am trying to install griddb_python in my project but I am unable to resolve the issue I am facing during the installation.
I followed through the errors and found out swig and pcre are to be installed. So, I installed them and now I am facing error:
Building wheel for griddb_python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.(subprocess-exited-with-error)

 src/ContainerInfo.cpp:89:48: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
              mContainerInfo = {containerName, type, propsCount, columnInfoList, rowKeyAssigned};
 


This is the error you get when you don't have the GridDB c-client on your machine but try to install the GridDB python client. You can see here it's listed as a prereq: https://github.com/griddb/python_client
The reason for this is the python client is built on top of the c-client with SWIG (kind of like a wrapper). So first install the c-client through the .deb or .rpm package and try again
